# How to uninstall a DLL using InstallUtil /u while running the uninstall wizard of InstallShield Limited Edition?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-action, installshield-le, mmc

I am creating an installer using InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition using which I am installing an MMC Snap-in.To install it for the 64-bit console, I am using a custom action on `After Register Product` which executes the following command:

```
[WindowsFolder]\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil [INSTALLDIR]\<SnapIn DLL>
```

This installs the snap-in successfully. But, where do I add the uninstall action for the same? i.e. running the `InstallUtil /u <SnapIn DLL>`

The only event for uninstall I see is `After System Changes` and the files in the `[INSTALLDIR]` get removed before this event occurs.

So, how can I run `[WindowsFolder]\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil /u [INSTALLDIR]\<SnapIn DLL>` during uninstallation?